# Как изменить стандартное поведение search в react-select?

Tags: reactjs, select, search

У меня есть компонент Select. Я задаю свою функцию для поиска по его значениям через пропс "onInputChange" и в результате поискового запроса на сервер загружаю в селект новые options. Но наравне с моей функцией отрабатывает внутренний поиск по options. Я бы хотела отменить нативное поведение внутри Select И оставить своё.

e preventdefault не поможет, т.к. в "e" лежит тип события

```
const MyComponent = ({selectedValue, setSelectedValue, optionsFromProps}) => {

  const onSearch = (value, e) => {
   // request for new options
   // and set this options to store
  };

  return (
    <Select {...someProps}
            value={selectedValue}
            options={optionsFromProps}
            onInputChange={onSearch}
            onChange={setSelectedValue}
    />
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение: добавить атрибут filterOption={option => option}.
В данном случае он никак не фильтрует опшены для отображения в листе меню - что мне собственно и требовалось